# Importing cert from Ubuntu certificate authority to Windows Server 2022

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, certificate

In our environment we have recently created a Ubuntu based CA, we want to utilise this on our windows environments.

I was following a tutorial for how to implement the CA and I don't know if I'm just not googling the right thing but I couldn't find anything related to what I was doing and it feels like I'm going round in circles.

I've followed this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-and-configure-a-certificate-authority-ca-on-ubuntu-20-04, and am at the point where I've created my ca.crt and I'm ready to give it out but when trying to link any cert in windows it's trying to retrieve it from local storage and I can't see anywhere on windows to specify the CA cert server name and get this all working.

I've seen a ton of information on setting up a CA between machines on linux and a linux based CA, or a windows ca on linux clients, etc

I have no experience setting a CA up as our last one was built without any documentation and is now broken

Any help would be appreciated and sorry if this is a stupid question lmao

Comment: What's your question? Sounds like you need to distribute the trusted root cert and any subordinate cert from your Linux CA's to the WIndows devices.  If that's the case you can do that through GPO's.  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/deployment/distribute-certificates-to-client-computers-by-using-group-policy

Comment: @TheCleaner thanks for the help, I had a look at the docs and I'm still a bit confused by how I get the cer from my ca to the client? This line is stumping me: `On the File to Import page, type the path to the appropriate certificate files (for example, \\fs1\c$\fs1.cer), and then click Next.`

Comment: You will export the cer to a shared folder location somewhere (SMB share, CIFS share, etc.) and use that path for the GPO.

Comment: @TheCleaner, thanks! I was under the impression the server spoke directly with the CA and retrieved the cert from the server itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to export the certificate somewhere that it can be imported into a GPO for your Windows AD environment.

[Create an SSL Certificate Authority on Linux and Use It in Windows AD](https://www.paladinsec.com/create-an-ssl-certificate-authority-on-linux-and-use-it-in-windows-ad/) will walk you through the steps.  I would recommend NOT using the default domain policy but instead creating a new GPO called "Distribute Linux CA root cert" and setting that up according to the link and then applying that GPO to the root of the domain as well as the domain controllers OU.

If you aren't using AD at all, then you'll need to manually export the certificate and then import it manually into the Windows servers trusted root store.  At that point the servers will trust the Linux CA and any certificates it issues.